# Confirming resistor value

Tags: resistors, identification

[image]

Hi I  need to replace this resistor but I  am not convinced that I have read it correctly  at 180m ohm. Can someone  confirm please?  The third band looks like pink but I ha w read it as violet.

Comment: We first have to agree about the colors: For me this looks like red/white/orange/gold.

Comment: @StefanWyss I'd say brown/grey/???/gold, personally. It'd help to see what exactly the resistor is being used for.

Comment: Could you explain something of what the circuit this is a part of is doing? A schematic would be very helpful.

Comment: COULD be a well baked 39k. Or ... - as others note, more detail helps us help you.

Comment: Sorry I have no drawings. The board is a control board from a bosch dishwasher.  The lnk304gn step down switching regulator  next to it is also toast.

Comment: If you can find a good board with a good resistor, measure that.

Comment: It's a wire wound resistor.  I measured the short end at 10ohm but could not get a reading from the long piece

Comment: One method would be to touch the tip of a hot soldering iron to the first band (looks to be brown), as the band over heats observe if it turns to the shade of the 3rd band.  If it does then you may have a 180 ohm part. If the resistor is a wire wound part as you say then lower values are more likely.

Answer (score 0):

Although we might tell you what we THINK the value of the resistor is, it may or may not be correct (our observation is as good as yours).

If this resistor is crucial in the circuit, it might be best to use a **multi-meter** (set to **"Impedance mode"**) and measure the resistance of this resistor by touching the 2 leads of the multi-meter to the 2 ends of the resistor, to find the value.

Comment: Thanks but I had already tried that. After some extensive research online It turns out hat it's a 100r resistor . I have the board working again. Thanks for all the help.                     Dougie